# Using ToCoveoFieldName in backend

Tags: coveo

Is there a way to get Coveo equivalent field name helper such as `ToCoveoFieldName` in `CoveoProcessParsedRestResponseArgs` pipeline code? Basically I am trying to see if a property of `SearchResult` item is of certain value and based on it create a new property.

```
var db = NewStuff();

foreach (SearchResult result in response.Results)
{
    result["isNew"] = "201612" == result.Raw["fyearandmonth11031"].ToString();
}
```

The field `fyearandmonth11031` needs to be translated from Sitecore field (`YearAndMonth`) to a Coveo field name.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not sitecore related at all and only Coveo related. It should be asked on https://answers.coveo.com instead.

Comment: Yet when we talk to Coveo, they recommended to ask it here. Although I think this is still valid since the helper in question is for Coveo for Sitecore module.

Comment: Can you tell me who told you to ask it here please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is most likely `IFieldNameTranslator`. You need a `SitecoreHelper` to get an instance for a specific index.

Since the pipeline can be run without a context, you have to validate whether the CurrentContextItem is null before trying to convert it in an indexable.

The following code should work for your use case:

```cs
ISitecoreHelper sitecoreHelper = new SitecoreHelper();
IFieldHelper translator = new FieldHelper();
if (p_Args.CurrentContextItem != null) {
    bool usePrefix = false;
    IIndexable indexable = p_Args.CurrentContextItem.ToIndexable();
    ISearchIndex index = m_SitecoreHelper.GetSearchIndex(indexable);
    IFieldNameTranslator translator = m_SitecoreHelper.GetFieldNameTranslator(index);
    string translatedField = translator.ToCoveoFieldName(indexable, "field", usePrefix);
    // Use that translated field here
}
```